# How to view TFS Scrum Bugs under PBIs in Backlog?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, backlog

When checking in TFS under Work\Backlogs\Backlog items, any Sprint, I can see PBIs and linked tasks under them. However bugs I noticed are treated at the same level as PBIs, meaning I can never see a Bug under a PBI, but I can see a task under a Bug.

Is this because the understanding is that Bugs are an occurrence after PBIs are marked as "Done" in a future sprint (since all PBIs should have gone through testing until completely reviewed and accepted).

I'm thinking if this is the logic then Bugs in their own right are like a PBI - a new "Problem" Backlog Item lol.

We are getting confused because we at first wanted to see Bugs under PBIs or Tasks to see what the bug is associated with, but because a bug may occur from an assortment of development done in the future, it's treated as independent on the same level as a PBI. Am I understanding this correctly or is there a way to put bug under a PBI\Task in the backlog when viewing (I know you can link it as so, but I mean for viewing purposes in the backlog). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure team settings to set your team's preferences for tracking bugs.

To see Bugs under PBIs, you can select the option **Bugs are managed with tasks** under **Working with bugs** tab. See [Show bugs on backlogs and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/show-bugs-on-backlog?view=vsts) for details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the board settings page, you can configure bugs display behavior.

They can be treated as Tasks, in which case they show as children of PBIs, at the same level as Tasks, and are displayed on the sprint board.

Or, they can be treated as Requirements, in which case they are shown at the same level as PBIs and can have Tasks created underneath them.

It sounds like you currently have the latter behavior enabled, but would prefer the former.

This is configurable at the Team level. You can [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/show-bugs-on-backlog?view=vsts) one behavior or the other, but not both. This means that for a given team, bugs can either be Requirements, or they can be Tasks. They cannot be Requirements in some situations and Tasks in some others.

Also note that if you've upgraded from an earlier version of TFS, you may have to manually enable the feature, since it required some changes to the process templates that you or your TFS administrator may not have made.